# Azure Key Vault - List all Apps (Managed Identities) requesting secretes

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to run a log query or an az powershell command etc to retrieve a list of all apps (Manged Identities) that make requests to an Azure Key Vault? It would be even better if I could get the count of requests per application over a given time.

Thanks

Comment: You'd like to know what app visited azure key vault and how many times per application visit vault in a given time? If so, can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/logging?tabs=Vault) help you?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you. It would be good if this could be linked to an App Insights instead of a storage account so there is less set up and configuration. Thanks for your help @Tiny-wa. Happy to accept as the answer.

Comment: It's good that feature could meet your request. I've added it as answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure key vault provided 'logging' feature to offer monitor to access suituation, and the logging information will be stored in an Azure storage account.

Here's the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/logging?tabs=Vault) which tells details.